# How do I send a pdf file to a jupyter notebook, process it in the notebook and then display the result in a webapp

Tags: python, next.js, jupyter-notebook, nlp, large-language-model

I have a jupyter notebook that can take a pdf file, run an llm model and then return the summary of the pdf.

I'm think of a way to have a webapp where a user can upload their pdf, the pdf gets sent to the notebook and the summary gets displayed to the user.

I know how to build the user interface (using nextjs) but I'm not sure how to build the process. Do I hot the jupyter notebook somewhere? How do I send the pdf from my nextjs app to the notebook> I'm pretty confused.

I would really appreciate suggestions please.

Comment: I think you would need a proper backend/api to respond and process the requests from you front in NextJS and I don't think jupyter is able to do this. There exists technologies to do this with python, to name a few you could use python cgi script, flask, django...

Comment: I'm working on framework for converting notebooks to web apps. You can directly convert notebook to web app with it. It is called Mercury https://github.com/mljar/mercury If you need any help, please just create an issue.

Comment: @pplonski this looks good! Would take a deeper look and see if it fits my intent. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a API, at the user interface create a POST request which will be collected at the endpoint in your python code. Through another POST request through the API in python code the endpoint in your webapp will receive the summary.

It doesn't matter as such whether it's a .py file (python script) or .ipynb file (jupyter notebook).

For working with API you can refer to: https://realpython.com/api-integration-in-python/

Comment: Ah, I see. This looks like the practical approach. Would give this a shot.